# Windows shutdown processes termination sequence

Tags: windows, process, vbscript

Do you know the Windows shutdown process is implemented? Does it has some criteria to avoid inter-process communication problems between child and parent processes?

This question originated from an suspicious (apparent) coincidence situation on a script terminating successfully and shutdown of the machine [over-described on the original written question replied by Falcon Kirtaran].

Comment: This question was written on 2am local time, I was tired. Sorry about that.
Basically I want to know more about the details of the shutdown process of windows.

Comment: Re-written the question, now it is a real question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are asking.  However, if you are interested in why the process appeared to terminate as though it was just about to finish normally, it's because windows first sends a signal to all the running programs as though the user exited them normally (eg. by pressing the X button in the top right of the window).  If they do not close within a set period of time, the system will either force-terminate them or give the user the option to do so ("end task").

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does windows first signals the child process and then the parent ones? Is there any order or sequence to the termination process, or are the signal sent in parallel from an arbitrary sequence?

Comment: @jpmartins: Windows does not distinguish between parent and child processes.  All processes are considered peers.  The shutdown message is not sent in any particular order.